# PHP calendar Today background-color dont run

Tags: php

I have one issue with setting "today" with a different background-color, but it doesn't run!!!

```
//CSS
  .today{
      background-color: yellow;
  }
```

```
      //print day number [Edited]

  $dayToCompare= $dayString."/".$monthString."/".$year;
  $todayDate =  date("d/m/Y"); // [edited] old date( "d/m/Y") for date("j/m/Y")
  if( $todayDate == $dayToCompare ){
      echo "<td align='center' class='today' ><a href='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?mes=".$monthString."&dia=".$dayString."&año=".$year."&v=TRUE' >$i</a></td>";
  }else{      echo "<td align='center'><a href='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?mes=".$monthString."&dia=".$dayString."&año=".$year."&v=TRUE' >$i</a></td>";}
```

Thanks !!!

Comment: debug $dayToCompare and $todayDate... are equal ? and the second echo should not be in an else ?

Comment: yes but is equal with or without "else" ..$todaydate and and $dayToCompare never macth

Comment: So, all the days are set without `class='today'`?

Comment: yes every day, even today ...

Comment: add this before your if: `echo $todayDate."=".$dayToCompare;` and tell us the result

Comment: tested? what result are you getting for today date?

Comment: Thanks  artur99, I was all day with this and could not see the differences.

the "visual comparison" shows that as given me 8/09/2014 = 08/09/2014 so here the error is in the digits of the day 8 vs. 08
only I have to change date ("d / m / Y") for ("j / m / Y");

many thanks !!! and sorry for the newville issue!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks artur99, I was all day with this and could not see the differences. the "visual comparison" shows that as given me 8/09/2014 = 08/09/2014 so here the error is in the digits of the day 8 vs. 08 only I have to change date ("d / m / Y") for ("j / m / Y"); many thanks !!! and sorry for the newville issue! –